# ajax call fails to maintain it's state when a button is clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've have the following example code (it can be copied as it is, and run to figure out the problem).

**index.php**

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:30px;width:100%;">
        <div style="height:20px;width:15%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <a href="" id="1" class="reprezentant">AAA</a>
        </div>
        <div style="height:20px;width:5%;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="height:20px;width:15%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <a href="" id="4" class="reprezentant">BBB</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>

    <div style="height:200px;width:20%;float:left;" id="tabel"></div>
    <div style="height:200px;width:78%;float:left;" id="content"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div style="height:30px;width:100%;">
        <div style="height:20px;width:5%;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="height:20px;width:15%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <a href="" id="btn4">SIZ</a>
        </div>
        <div style="height:20px;width:5%;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="height:20px;width:15%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <a href="" id="btn5">SIL</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.reprezentant').click(function(e){
            var rep = $(this).attr('id');
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "tabel.php",
                data: {rep:rep},
                success: function(resp){
                    $('#tabel').html(resp);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#btn4').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "siz.php",
                success: function(resp){
                    $('#content').html(resp);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#btn5').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sil.php",
                success: function(resp){
                    $('#content').html(resp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**tabel.php**

```
<?php $rep = $_POST['rep']; ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php
        for ($i=1;$i<=$rep;$i++){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="locatie" id="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo 'Name',$i;?></a>
                </td>
            </tr><?php
        }?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var loc, btn;

$('.locatie').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loc = $(this).attr('id');
});

$('a[id^=btn4]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "siz.php",
        data: {idlocatie: loc},
        success: function(html){
            $('#content').html(html);
        }
    });
});
$('a[id^=btn5]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sil.php",
        data: {idlocatie: loc},
        success: function(html){
            $('#content').html(html);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**siz.php**

```
<?php
$idloc = isset($_POST['idlocatie']) ? $_POST['idlocatie'] : '';
echo $idloc,' ';
?>
SIZ
```

**sil.php**

```
<?php
$idloc = isset($_POST['idlocatie']) ? $_POST['idlocatie'] : '';
echo $idloc,' ';
?>
SIL
```

After clicking AAA, Name1, and SIZ, the index.php looks like this:
[image]

- When I press AAA, an ajax call, which contains a number, will be send to tabel.php, and in the left side of index.php page will be displayed a table with as many rows in it as the sent number. If I press BBB, an ajax call, which contains another number, will be send to tabel.php, and a table with as many rows in it as the sent number will be displayed in the left side of the index.php page.
- Each table contains some names, and each name being a link, has an id of a number.
- When a name is clicked, it's id (the number), is send to both siz.php and sil.php files.
- Now, when any of SIZ or SIL is clicked, it should display in the middle of the page, the number of the id for the clicked name from the left table, plus the name of the button that was clicked (SIZ or SIL).

Problem 1: if I press multiple times SIZ or SIL, then the number sent by table.php will be gone. My question would be, how to solve this problem, so that the number stays in siz.php/sil.php script, no matter how many times I press SIZ or SIL?

Problem 2: now, to be able to see the number of the Name, I must follow this steps:

- press AAA or BBB
- press on one of the names from the left table
- press SIZ or SIL
  I'd wish to dynamically send the id of the Name (when I click on one of the Names), w/o the need of pressing SIZ or SIL. Can this thing be done?

Thank you!

Comment: "if I press multiple times SIZ or SIL, then the number sent by table.php will be gone", do you mean pressing them while the previous request has not returned?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I've said that because in my real project, siz.php and sil.php contain some other buttons, and when they are clicked, the content changes accordingly. But, initially,I must press SIZ/SIL to see the siz.php or sil.php. So, as I've mention it in Problem 1, when I press multiple times on SIZ/SIL, then the response varies from "1 SIZ" to just "SIZ". And my problem is that I don't know how to selve it, in the sense that I need to always get the same response, which is "1 SIZ" (that is, a number (the one sent from tabel.php), followed by the name of the button clicked (SIZ or SIL).

Comment: please scale this down to a minimal representation of the problem and remove all irrelevant code

Comment: You (probably) have to wait for the current request to come back before pressing the same button again. This would mean disable the button on send, and on return (success or error), re-enable it.

Comment: looks like spaghetti code to me. You should not pass scripts that way, youre just going to make a mess for yourself. Try placing all your JS in one place.

Comment: @charlietfl But I've already scaled it down as much as I could. All the code presented is relevant for being able to find the problem.

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm currently in dev mode, so I need the js code in every page, so I can easy follow the logic, and to be able to easily fix the errors, if any...